# Python lists and for loops. How do I communicate to the for loop that I intend to work on subsequent items and not the first one only?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am a newbie in python and I am working on a function that I expect to pass a string like `abcd` and it outputs something like `A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd`.

I have created the following.

`

```
def mumbler(s):
    chars = list(s)
    mumbled = []
    result = []
    for char in chars:
        caps = char.upper()
        num = chars.index(char)
        low = char.lower()
        mumbled.append( caps+ low*num)
    for i in mumbled:
        result.append(i+'-')
        result = ''.join(result)
    return result[:-1]
```

`

It works for most cases. However, when I pass a string like `Abcda`. It fails to return the expected output, in this case, `A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd-Aaaaa`.
How should I go about solving this? 
Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: `.index` returns **the first index**, use `enumerate` as you iterate instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in a much simpler way using list comprehension and `enumerate`

```
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> '-'.join([c.upper() + c.lower()*i for i,c in enumerate(s)])
'A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd'
```

Comment: With Python 3.6+ you can also use f-strings: `'-'.join([f'{c.upper()}{c.lower()*i}' for i, c in enumerate(s)])`

Comment: Thank you. Solves my problem and its very optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Go for a simple *1-liner* -  `next()` on `count` for maintaining the times to repeat and `title()` for title-casing:

```
from itertools import count

s = 'Abcda'
i = count(1)

print('-'.join([(x * next(i)).title() for x in s]))
# A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd-Aaaaa
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your own code work, you'll just need to convert the `result` list to string outside your second for-loop:

```
def mumbler(s):
    chars = list(s)
    mumbled = []
    result = []
    for char in chars:
        caps = char.upper()
        num = chars.index(char)
        low = char.lower()
        mumbled.append( caps+ low*num)
    for i in mumbled:
        result.append(i+'-')
    result = ''.join(result)
    return result[:-1]

mumbler('Abcda')
'A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd-Aaaaa'
```

Comment: Works too. Thank you